# On a WebSphere Portal server, I get incorrect web pages instead of 404 errors

Tags: java, security, http, web, websphere-portal

I use WebSphere Portal server.

Say my website is `example.com`. I click on a link in the header and it goes to `example.com/y` which is a valid page. However, if I enter `example.com/y/foobar` into the address bar, and no such resource exists, the webpage `example.com/y` is returned, with `example.com/y/foobar` in the address bar.

How can I make it throw a 404 error instead, as it should since such a resource does not exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's your actual question?

Comment: SilverlightFox it's a valid question about portal

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the way WebSphere Portal server handles access control. If you have a page which unauthenticated users can access it will redirect you to that page rather than throwing a 404. The way to fix this is to make sure pages aren't accessible to unauthenticated users in the Portal admin console.

That said, what it may do instead of throwing a 404 is redirect you to the login page.